# Is there any event fired for Xtragrid on removing filters?

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, xtragrid

I have Xtragrid, when I filter a column on some value it comes as best fit but when I unfilter, it cuts some of the values. To prevent this, I want to do best fit on unfiltering. So, is there any event fired on unfiltering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found one. 
It is called ColumnFilterChanged

Comment: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ColumnFilterChangedtopic